# Self-updating site

Tags: scripting, content-management-system

I want to make a site that updates itself based upon changes on another site. For example, every time certain external site posts an article with a specific tag, my site should update and post a notice reporting that.

What tools would you recommend for doing such task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use [RSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS) or [JSON](http://www.json.org/) on the first site and make a feed of all the changes. If I can't do that due to ownership, I'd just parse the site with [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) and [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) every few minutes to record changes via that.

I'd run the second site using the [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) web framework and [Python](http://www.python.org/), as it's easy for me to churn out things quickly with Python.

Answer (score 0):

You could also implement [Pubsubhubbub](http://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/) for near-realtime notifications. It's based on Atom.